# Does addSideDatabase not work with Google Maps Engine Lite? Why no callbacks?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Exploring the addSideDatabase method in Google Code Playground (http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#adding_a_side_database), I tried to replace the URL with one for my Google Maps Engine Lite map (https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zaet3r0aK3bg.kEC1j3RZYDKw).  It didn't work.  Is Google Maps Engine Lite not supported?  I can't find anything either way in the docs.  Furthermore, why are neither the sideDatabaseSuccess nor sideDatabaseFail callbacks invoked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if Google Maps Engine Lite is supported, I think it possibly is as that has partly replaced the Google Earth Builder platform which did allow for such connections.

In any case usually to use any professional/enterprise functions you must make sure to pass your client ID when loading the actual Earth API. e.g.

```
var params = {"other_params":"client=CLIENTID&sensor=false"};
google.load("earth", "1", params);
```

See: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/#sidedatabase

Also note that if your map is private you'll need to provide authentication credentials along when you connect.